# roundCube popup message alert title ERRORTITLE

Tags: php, roundcube

[image]

I couldn't find a way to change the title, I have found the error message in Localization files but I couldn't find the ERRORTITLE text to change. I have added some labels to plugin's localization file as like $labels['error'] = "Test Title"; $labels['error_title'] = "Test Title"; but nothing has been changed. Thans for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the skin. 
In the filel ../includes/links.html you must add at end the following line:

```
<roundcube:add_label name="errortitle" />
```

Solved for me.